# Not able to permanently set environmental variable PATH

Tags: linux

I want to add the path to `pycharm.sh` to `PATH` (Pycharm community Edition 5.0.2), which is stored in `/opt/pycharm-community-5.0.2/bin`. At first I added the following line to `/etc/environment`, which was an empty file before:

```
PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/opt/pycharm-community-5.0.2/bin"
```

Afterward I tried to start Pycharm via terminal, without success:

```
$ pycharm
bash: pycharm: command not found.
```

My next step was to change the value of PATH inside the first if statement in `/etc/profile` as follows:

```
if [ "`id -u`" -eq 0 ]; then
  PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/opt/pycharm-community-5.0.2/bin"
else
  PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/opt/pycharm-community-5.0.2/bin"
fi
export PATH
```

I restarted the system after each step, but I still the receive the same error message.

Is there another way to permanently set the variable? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @J.P.Quenord-Zermingore: That works great. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your executable filename is `pycharm.sh`, not *pycharm*. Try typing that instead.

You could also try `which pycharm.sh`, which attempts to locate given command using PATH environment variable, to see that your configuration works.

Comment: I tried typing pycharm.sh instead. It didn't work. But I managed to solve the problem by changing PATH in .bashrc. Thanks @J.P.Quenord-Zermingore.

Comment: Also, check the value of PATH variable before thinking it has not been added.  Is your terminal a login terminal?  this is also one thing that could make you not to get the variables on place.